# moving edit text along with soft keyboard android

Tags: android, android-edittext, soft-input-panel

I am having an comment edit text in my application. The edit text is aligned at the bottom of the screen. when edit text is focused i want to move edit text alone with soft keyboard without changing other views in layout similar to comment edit box in facebook. I tried adjustpan in manifest but it moves all views up with soft keyboard. adjustresize in manifest hides some view.please provide suggestions.

Comment: I am also facing same problem. Any luck ? Can you please share with me ?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this inside your Android manifest file..

```
<activity name="YourActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize">
</activity>
```

or

```
<activity name="YourActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan">
</activity>
```

Please also [read this for ref/Clarity](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/04/updating-applications-for-on-screen.html)

Comment: i tried with resize it hides some of the view, i want only to move the edit text with keyboard without changing the position of other view.but resize and  adjustpan affects all the view

Comment: same problem. need space between edittext and soft keyboard to display errors?

Answer (score 1):

Add

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

in your AndroidManifest file (in activity property)

Answer (score 0):

`dialog.getWindow().
setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);`

Its also working with out manifest file entry